# Can I set flutter widget's property with map or somthing key-value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use key-value map when I setting parameters in a widget.

I think it makes code more simple and actually I did that on javascript, reactJS

But, flutter doesn't support my way so, I am very confused.

I did like this. But it doesn't work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

 final String title;

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

final Map map = {
 'color':Colors.red,
 'width':10,
 'height':100,
 'padding':const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), 
 'margin':const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
 };
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(widget.title),
     ),
     body: Container(map)
   );
 }
}
```

Is there any good idea of like this?

thank you so much read my question.

Answer (score 0):

The least you can do in flutter to make this property reusable in many other widget is defining them globally for that class.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

var _padding =  EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
Color _color = Colors.red;
var _height=  100;
var _width = 10;
var _margin= EdgeInsets.all(8.0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Container(
    color:_color,
    padding:_padding,
    margin:_margin,
    height:_height,
    width:_width,
    )
  );
}
}
```